# How to get live row count as Jasper prints reports

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, jasper-reports

I've developed a web application using jsp that has a list of contents which are placed in an `ArrayList`. I've tried various methods to implement this, tried the `AsynchronousFillHandle` , `AJAX` , `Scriptlet`. But I just can't get it done properly.

What I'm trying to achieve here is, while the JasperExportManager is filling records row by row, I want to display the number of rows that have been printed (say Live status of number of records printed) in the webpage.

For Example

`267 out of 645588 records printed`
`5692 out of 645588 records printed`
`34677 out of 645588 records printed`

After two days of unsuccessful attempts, I decided to use a shortcut, I wrote a scriptlet file, which will print the count of records being printed to a txt file in the same directory, 
Scriptlet code:

```
public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException{
      count = (Integer) this.getVariableValue("count");
      BufferedWriter br = null;
      try {
          br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:/jasperreports-5.6.0/test/viewTasks/WebContent/value.txt")));
          br.write(new String(""+count));
          br.close();
          Thread.sleep(200);
      }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

and then used another ajax request to read data from the text file and display it in the browser, which was again unsuccessful as the ajax request returned only the previously stored value (i.e. Although the changes take place in the .txt file, AJAX request returned only the value which was there before the program execution took place. I guess it is because, the changes happen in the local directory and doesn't get reflected in the server). The AJAX code is as follows,
Webpage code:

```
<script>
    function startPrinting() {
      xhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState >= 1) {
            document.getElementById('total')style.display = "";
            setTimeout(function() { getStat(); }, 6000); //calls the function to start updating status
        }
      };
      xhttp1.open("POST", "statusServlet", true);
      xhttp1.send();
    } //This function is to start the printing processes
    function getStat(){
        myvar=setInterval(function() {reval()}, 3000);
        function reval(){
            if(xhttp1.readyState>2){
                xhttp1.abort();
            }
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var prev = "";
            rawFile.open("GET","value.txt" , true);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {
                        allText = rawFile.responseText;
                        if(prev===allText){
                            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = allText;
                            return;
                        }
                        prev = allText;
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = allText;
                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

**While using this code, If the file .txt is kept active inside the eclipse IDE, the values get reflected in the webpage, I really don't know why or how, but when the text file is kept active (I know it's weird), somehow the AJAX request returns the values correctly. Is there anyway to get this code to work without having to keep the .txt file active? Is there any other way to achieve the live row status of Jasper export other than writing and reading from a file?**

NOTE: I'm using JAVA EE IDE from Eclipse with Tomcat 7.0 as server

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JasperReports isn't designed for real-time interactivity. Also, reading from a file is brittle at best. This strikes me as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/132527).